# Javascript function working intermittently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a burger icon made of three divs in a container. When this icon is clicked I call a Javascript function. The first part triggers a CSS transition to create an X and change the opacity of one of the burger icon divs. The second part of the function makes the nav menu come into view and out of view by changing the amount of left.

When I run this in the browser the first part works fine, however the second one works intermittently. This is also caused the state of the burger icon not to match correct with the nav menu.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/orderoftheditch/pen/jOMqXEg)

```
 <script>
function burgerNav(x) {
 x.classList.toggle("burgerAnimate");
  if (document.getElementById("menu-container").style.left = "-450px")  {
    document.getElementById("menu-container").style.left = "0px";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("menu-container").style.left = "-450px";
  }
}   </script>`
```

Answer (score 6):

That is not a comparison but assignment in the if clause. Try this instead:

```
if (document.getElementById("menu-container").style.left === "-450px") {}
```